# What's difference between this: sudo find /usr/local/mysql/data -type f -exec rm {} ';' 

Tags: command-line, unix, mysql

What's difference between this:

```
sudo find /usr/local/mysql/data -type f -exec rm {} ';'
```

and this:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql/data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo find /usr/local/mysql/data -type f -exec rm {} ';'
```

sudo will make it run as root, then you use `find -type f` to get all the files(**just files**) in `/usr/local/mysql/data`

the `-exec rm{}` will be called for each item found and will remove the file.

So this will remove files recursively but it will **NOT remove any directories**. Also not that the `rm` command is used without `-f` argument(force)

```
rm -rf /usr/local/mysql/data
```

This command will completely remove everything in the given path, **directories and files are removed.** `-f` is used so there will be no prompts for the issuing user.

Comment: so the curlies **{}** will contain the results of the `find… -type f` portion of the statement when `rm` is `exec`uted?

Comment: yes, you are correct Meltemi. When using find in combination of -exec the String {} will be replaced with the full path to the current file.

Answer (score 2):

The former will remove only files. The latter will remove the entire directory structure.

Comment: what's the `';'` mean?

Comment: It terminates the `-exec` predicate.

Comment: meaning, you could add another -exec doing something else ...

Comment: Meaning you can add another predicate without it being interpreted as an argument for the command in the `-exec` predicate.

Answer (score 0):

`find /usr/local/mysql/data -type f -delete` will delete only regular files. Directories will stay

`rm -rf /usr/local/mysql/data` Will remove anything.